# Filter results based on the user ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, es6-class

Currently I have a controller method that filters the results by default and returns books that have the `bookStatus` `in stock`. But I want the list to have all the books irrespective of the `bookStatus` by default and should only apply the filter logic when the user triggers it. I have tried conditional statements but it really does not do its thing. Here is my controller:

```
exports.getBooks = async (req, res, next) => {

    const bookList = new BookList(Book.find(), req.query)
        .filter(req)
        .sort()
        .paginate();

    const books = await bookList.query;
    
    res.status(200)
        .json({
            books,
        });
};
```

Here is the BookList class that has the methods:

```
class BookList {
    constructor(query, queryString) {
        this.query = query;
        this.queryString = queryString;
    }

    filter() {
        filter(req) {
        let bookStatus = {bookStatus: 'in stock', userid: req.params.userid};

        this.query = this.query.find(bookStatus);
        return this;
    }
    }

    sort() {
        if (this.queryString.sort) {
            const sortBy = this.queryString.sort.split(',').join(' ');
            this.query = this.query.sort(sortBy);
        } else {
            this.query = this.query.sort('-createdAt');
        }

        return this;
    }

    paginate() {
        const page = Number(this.queryString.page) || 1;
        const limit = Number(this.queryString.limit) || 100;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

        this.query = this.query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

        return this;
    }
}
module.exports = BookList;
```

Comment: How would the user trigger the filter method to filter by 'in stock'? Is it a query parameter?

Comment: Can you share the conditional statements you tried?

Comment: @CascadiaJS I did not want it to be a query parameter, so it gets called and returns the results from the db

Comment: @boomchickawawa How does the user trigger the filter when they send a request?

Comment: @CascadiaJS Like I said, it is done by default

Comment: @Manoj I did this `if(this.queryString.filter) {
            let bookStatus = {bookStatus: 'in stock', userid: req.params.userid};

            this.query = this.query.find(bookStatus);
        } else {
            this.query = this.query.find({ userid: req.params.userid });
        }
        return this `
Not sure how to edit code in comments, sorry for the poor format. Anyway, this returns the results as expected but I dont think this is the ideal way to do this

Comment: @boomchickawawa I think what you can try is `let statement = {userid: req.params.userid}; 
if(this.queryString.filter) {
   statement.bookStatus = 'in stock';
};
this.query.find(statement);` 
something like this should work i think.